# Trying to understand "_root"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get an actionscript code used in a Flash CS5 example and make a ActionScript class using it in Flash Builder. And I'm trying to understand the `_root` property.

[This page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary633.html) have a brief explanation about the `_root` property, but it is too vague.

My question is: What is the "_root" that exists only when the ActionScript is placed in the Flash CS5 project? How do I reference it in my class in Flash Builder? (it is an instance of what?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20090615191715/http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1952513

I can't think of a better explanation of stage vs. root and what each means.

Comment: Cool. Could you copy the text here? (as maybe the link change in the future, and we lose it)

Comment: Kirupa is not going anywhere, that post was made in 2006. That and the text is -huge-

Comment: @Aaron Thanks. The link is dead.

Comment: @nathanb Link fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a wire crossed - there is no such thing as `_root` in AS3. In AS1/AS2, `_root` was basically a global variable pointing to the stage (it's actually a little more complicated, since AS2 had a slightly messy way of organizing display objects).

In AS3, the closest analogy is the [stage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#stage) property, but actually due to AS3's robust way of managing the display hierarchy you don't actually need to use `stage` very often. Anyway, for AS3 programming the only time you ever need to think about a `_root` is if you load in an AS2 SWF (which you should probably avoid if you can).